# Backlight stuck off after xset dpms force off is used

Tags: brightness, macbook-pro, backlight

On a 2007 17" MacBook Pro, model A1212, running yakkety, the display gets stuck off if anything issues xset dpms force off (or suspend). If I move my finger along the trackpad or press keys, I can see that the panel wakes back up if I shine a light on it, but the backlight remains off. I am using the default Unity environment (which is actually the reason I am using Ubuntu - I was on Debian stable with KDE before, and did not encounter this issue).

If I press F1 or F2, I can see that the backlight notification appears and changes accordingly, but the backlight itself remains off. Also, if I write values to `/sys/class/backlight/apple_backlight/brightness`, those values stick, but the backlight still stays off.

I can get the backlight to turn on by telling the system to suspend (however, closing the lid does not work in this state; instead, I have to press the power button, the right arrow key twice, and then enter) and resuming it. Rebooting also works, of course. Sometimes, immediately after I press enter to select suspend, the backlight turns on (and then back off once the machine enters suspend.)

So, can I:

1) Prevent this from happening? What's causing the backlight to be stuck off after xset dpms force off is used, and how can I get it to come back on? Or...

2) Prevent xset dpms force off from being used? Since this is a MacBook, a brightness of 0 turns the backlight off. If I could set somewhere that the brightness should be set to 0 instead of xset dpms force off be used, that could be a workaround.